# Passing an entire row as an argument to spark udf through spark dataframe - throws AnalysisException

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to pass an entire row to the spark udf along with few other arguments, I am not using spark sql rather I am using **dataframe withColumn api**, but I am getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) col3#9 missing from col1#7,col2#8,col3#13 in operator !Project [col1#7, col2#8, col3#13, UDF(col3#9, col2, named_struct(col1, col1#7, col2, col2#8, col3, col3#9)) AS contcatenated#17]. Attribute(s) with the same name appear in the operation: col3. Please check if the right attribute(s) are used.;;
```

The above exception can be replicated using the below code:

```
    addRowUDF() // call invokes

    def addRowUDF() {
        import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
        import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

        val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(new SparkConf().set("master", "local[*]")).appName(this.getClass.getSimpleName).getOrCreate()

        import spark.implicits._
        val df = Seq(
          ("a", "b", "c"),
          ("a1", "b1", "c1")).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")
        execute(df)
      }

  def execute(df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) {

    import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
    def concatFunc(x: Any, y: String, row: Row) = x.toString + ":" + y + ":" + row.mkString(", ")

    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{ udf, struct }

    val combineUdf = udf((x: Any, y: String, row: Row) => concatFunc(x, y, row))

    def udf_execute(udf: String, args: org.apache.spark.sql.Column*) = (combineUdf)(args: _*)

    val columns = df.columns.map(df(_))

    val df2 = df.withColumn("col3", lit("xxxxxxxxxxx"))

    val df3 = df2.withColumn("contcatenated", udf_execute("uudf", df2.col("col3"), lit("col2"), struct(columns: _*)))

    df3.show(false)
  }
```

output should be:

```
+----+----+-----------+----------------------------+
|col1|col2|col3       |contcatenated               |
+----+----+-----------+----------------------------+
|a   |b   |xxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxx:col2:a, b, c    |
|a1  |b1  |xxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxx:col2:a1, b1, c1 |
+----+----+-----------+----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

That happens because you refer to column that is no longer in the scope. When you call:

```scala
val df2 = df.withColumn("col3", lit("xxxxxxxxxxx"))
```

it shades the original `col3` column, effectively making preceding columns with the same name accessible. Even if it wasn't the case, let's say after:

```
val df2 = df.select($"*", lit("xxxxxxxxxxx") as "col3")
```

the new `col3` would be ambiguous, and indistinguishable by name from the one defined brought by `*`.

So to achieve the required output you'll have to use another name:

```scala
val df2 = df.withColumn("col3_", lit("xxxxxxxxxxx"))
```

and then adjust the rest of your code accordingly:

```scala
df2.withColumn(
  "contcatenated", 
  udf_execute("uudf", df2.col("col3_") as "col3", 
  lit("col2"), struct(columns: _*))
).drop("_3")
```

If the logic is as simple as the one in the example, you can of course just inline things:

```scala
df.withColumn(
  "contcatenated", 
  udf_execute("uudf", lit("xxxxxxxxxxx") as "col3", 
  lit("col2"), struct(columns: _*))
).drop("_3")
```

Comment: "it overwrites the original col3 column and removes it from the plan" - this was something which I came to know but still need to understand deeply how it removed from the plan

though I will mark this as answered, but my actual issue was slightly different, I've solved that issue myself later in the day, thanks for your reply, :)

but could you please explain a bit on how did it remove from the logical plan.? i explored through the spark source but couldn't get much idea

Comment: spark source 

Dataset.scala

private[spark] def withColumns(colNames: Seq[String], cols: Seq[Column]): DataFrame = {...}